# Доступ к коллекциям в MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, администрирование

Можно ли в MongoDB разграничить доступ так чтоб у пользователей был доступ только определенным коллекциям?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, можно.

В роли пользователей можно указать конкретный ресурс - коллекцию в определенной базе. Синтаксис: `resource: { db: "БАЗА" , collection: "Коллекция" }`. Создайте свою роль и назначьте ее пользователю.

Пример роли с [официального сайта](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-roles-collection/#a-user-defined-role-specifies-privileges):

```
{
  _id: "myApp.appUser",
  role: "appUser",
  db: "myApp",
  privileges: [
       { resource: { db: "myApp" , collection: "" },
         actions: [ "find", "createCollection", "dbStats", "collStats" ] },
       { resource: { db: "myApp", collection: "logs" },
         actions: [ "insert" ] },
       { resource: { db: "myApp", collection: "data" },
         actions: [ "insert", "update", "remove", "compact" ] },
       { resource: { db: "myApp", collection: "system.js" },
         actions: [ "find" ] },
  ],
  roles: []
}
```